# Python post request not responding

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I have a Python GUI that interacts with some lab devices by sending POSTs through the device webpage. I used chrome developer tools to find out what information to send for each function and this approach has worked for everything except one button on the webpage.

The pertinent [output from developer tools is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Eok.png)

So I send this code as a post request

```
Post_data={'SUBMIT_FLOW' :'Zero Flow',
             'PRES_VAL' :''}
Encoded_data=urllib.urlencode(Post_data)
Request = urllib2.Request(url+'/configure_html_zero', Encoded_data)
```

Every other time I have done this strategy the device will run the function I want it to, but for this function it doesn't work. If I unpack the response to that request I get

```
<addinfourl at 205604872L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x000000000EE8F408>>
```

Here is the section of HTML code that this function corresponds to

```
<td class="main_table_data">
    <table ID="Zero" class="inner_table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <form name="config_zero" method="post" action="configure_html_zero">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Zero Flow" name="SUBMIT_FLOW" ID="ZeroFlow"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr> <!-- End Labels -->
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Zero Pressure" name="SUBMIT_PRES" ID="ZeroPressure"><input type="text" name="PRES_VAL" size="10"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</td>
```

I don't know HTML at all so I don't know if this is valuable.

And, if it is of any interest, here is [what the form looks like on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uRzR.png)

I'm not sending the data to the wrong URL, and I am using the same procedure as I have a dozen other times in my program. Any idea why this one is different? Does this have something to do with the blank value for "PRES_VAL"?

Comment: If you submit on the device web page with "PRES_VAL" empty does it work as it is supposed to? Also that response looks very suspicious. Are you sure this is the actual body of the response? Not sure what you mean by "unpack the response".

Comment: Yes, submitting with no entry for PRES_VAL does work. In fact, I didn't even know that input existed until yesterday.

By unpack I mean using `urllib2.urlopen(req_log_in)` and printing the response. If this is not the right way to do it let me know

Comment: What is the status of the response `resp.getcode()`? Also, what is the content of the response`resp.read()`. Here `resp=urllib2.urlopen(req_log_in)`. What you've posted in your question is the representation of a file object, we can't use much of it to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: resp.getcode() returns 200

Comment: resp.read() is too long to fit in the comments. I can edit my question, but it is over three pages long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resp.read()` and `resp.getcode()` should contain the description of any potential problem you're encountering. Is `resp.getcode()` anything other than 2xx? You should check against https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes . If `resp.read()` is very long then it likely has the content of an HTML page, you could save the contents in a HTML file and view it with a browser to check if it contains any indications of problems (validation errors). Without the actual device and the whole req/response info no one can help you except for providing debugging tips.

Comment: Thanks! resp.getcode() is returning 200 everytime, but clearly something is going wrong. I'll check out the HTML file and see what I can glean from it. I've been trying to get in touch with the device manufacturer for a while now but it is hard to talk to anyone who has a clue what I am talking about. Thanks for the tips, this is definitely more progress than I have made in a while